# Filling up Multiple JQuery Progress Bars dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a couple of Jquery Progress Bars, which I need to Fill up dynamically, each with a different value.

The HTML Code is attached Below:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
<form method="POST" action="ClearPoll">
    <div id="mydiv" class="Gadget">
        <input class="PercentageHid" type="hidden" value="36" name="Percentage">
            <object class="GadgetActualImage" type="image/jpeg" data="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/No_image_available.svg"> </object>

        <div class="Information">
            <input class="PollViewName" type="text" value="Potatoe Masher" placeholder="Please Enter the Gadget Name" name="Name" readonly="">
            <textarea id="" class="GadgetDescription" name="Comment" cols="10" rows="4" readonly="">You'll Never Stop Mashing ! </textarea>
        </div>
            <div id="Potatoe Masher" class="ProgressBar ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" title="Gadget Reputation: 36.0 % " data-options="80" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="36">
            <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style="width: 36%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="ClearPoll">
    <div id="mydiv" class="Gadget">
        <input class="PercentageHid" type="hidden" value="52" name="Percentage">
        <object class="GadgetActualImage" type="image/jpeg" data="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/No_image_available.svg"> </object>
    <div class="Information">
        <input class="PollViewName" type="text" value="Butter Slicer" placeholder="Please Enter the Gadget Name" name="Name" readonly="">
        <textarea id="" class="GadgetDescription" name="Comment" cols="10" rows="4" readonly="">No More Work </textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="Butter Slicer" class="ProgressBar ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" title="Gadget Reputation: 52.0 % " data-options="80" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="36">

    <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style="width: 36%;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Each Progress bar should take the value in the Hidden input field "Percentage"

My Current Javascript file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var text = $(this).find('[name="Percentage"]').val();   
   $(function() {
      alert(text);
      $('.ProgressBar').progressbar({
         value: parseInt(text)
      });
   });
});
```

The JavaScript code Works, but it sets the Percentage value to all Progress bar, not to the Respective one.

Essentially, what I need is to get the value in the hidden field and apply that value to the progress bar in the same form.

Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you need to initialize a plugin that requires instance specific data for multiple instances you need to loop over the elements and intialize individually, rather than initialize on the whole collection of elements at once:

In this case you could loop over each form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).find('[name="Percentage"]').val();
        /* iniitialize the progress bar within this form*/
        $(this).find('.ProgressBar').progressbar({
            value: parseInt(text)
        });
    });
});
```